# Wordpress Search Results - Check for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the custom post types in my wordpress blog and want to have a different icon for each type of post.

```
<?php if ( is_post_type( 'team' ) ) {
    echo '<img src="team.png" />';}
else
{
    echo '<img src="page.png" />';
}?>
```

But I get following error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_post_type().

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of WP are you using?  Looks like `is_post_type()` was deprecated...

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13747

You should probably use `get_post_type()` instead:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type

Comment: Yes, works! Thanks for your help.. Sure you wrote post_type_exists before… that didnt work :D